# Can I make a template operator<< overload that all classes can use? C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

If my question is confusing, what I basically mean is this:

in java if you System.out.println(class) it will default to the toString function and prints what ever is specified there. I was wondering if I could do something like that in C++. I should also probably mention I am not too good at c++ so there may be many errors in my example code.

```
class thing  {
    private:
            char *foo;
    public:
            thing(){   foo="asd";   }
            char* getString(){   return foo;   }
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, thing &abc);
    };

    template<typename T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, T &abc){
            out<<abc.getString();
            return out;   }


int main(){
            thing test;
            cout<<test;
            return 0;  }
```

I've tried to do this a few ways and I always get some kind of error.

Comment: `thing test()` is [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: Please SFINAE it at _least_!  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/281a89eeb4ef5896

Comment: Why do you have both `getString` _and_ the `operator<<`?  They both do the same thing so it's ambiguous which you want.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to replace the `<<` operator, not overload it. Your "overload" takes an ostream and any other type, which leaves nothing for the normal `<<` operator.

Comment: Additionally, it's more normal to have a `std::string to_string(const my_class_type&)` as a free function.  They're being added to standard C++ even.

Comment: @RedAlert: It's an overload. Overload resolution prefers non-template functions (and methods) over template functions, so this doesn't steal all arguments. Still, it will break all code which relied on an implicit conversion to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working version of your code, combined with @Mooing Duck's SFINAE check

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class thing  {
private:
        const char *foo;
public:
        thing(){   foo="asd";   }
        const char* getString() const {   return foo;   }
};

template<typename T, class = decltype(std::cout<<std::declval<T>().getString())>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, T const &abc){
    out<<abc.getString();
    return out;
}

int main(){
    thing test;
    cout<<test << 3;
    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f02aa9e7fd6731)

Comment: you should add `const`

Comment: @MooingDuck happy now?

Comment: Why do you need both overloads for getString()?

Comment: @user3521733 it is not required.

Comment: @user3521733 why? `enable_if` need a `bool` value condition, what condition do you want? unless you want to create a helper class `has_getstring<T>`

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer, but if it's no big deal, can some one summarize what the "class = decltype(std::cout<<std::declval<T>().getString())" part does. I don't know what a declval is or why it's needed there. Thanks again

Comment: @user3417909 it is used for [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). basically it try to figure out the result type in the expression in `decltype`. if it can't figure it out (i.e. does not have `getString` method), it won't pick this overload.

Comment: @user3417909: it sets the second template parameter equal to the return type of `std::cout<<abc.getString()`.  If `abc` doesn't _have_ a `.getString()` (like, say, `int`), then the compiler gives up on this function, and ignores it.  Thus, it won't try to use this function for `int` and `std::string` and `char*` and such.=, since they don't have `.getString()` members.  It works in exactly the same way that `enable_if` works.    `std::declval<T>()` pretends to create a `T`, and works no matter what constructors `T` does or does not have.  It can't _actually_ create a `T` though.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is okay. Though, arguably you've simply shifted the dependency from having an << overload to having the `getString()` member. You should pass by const-ref, though. Also, getString() should be const.

Comment: Would passing by const ref get rid of the errors? would I return constants or just make the functions constant?

Comment: Your code compiles for me (though with a warning about the string literal) when I remove the friend decl. That was preferred over the template.

Comment: Passing by const-ref is needed if you want it to work for const objects. In which case, getString also needs to be const.